# why I'm not able to use LIMIT and OFFSET in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get MAX - 1 record using below query but if I use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in query it is throwing error. Any other way can use this query to get Max - 1 row? I am using SQL Server

```
UPDATE [dbo].[ORDER_DETAIL] 
SET LINE_STATUS_CODE = 'C' 
WHERE RATE_STRUCTURE = 'LIST' 
  AND RATE_CODE = 'PRIMARY' 
  AND SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = @ip_master_customer_id  
  AND [ORDER_NO] = @ip_order_id 
  AND ORDER_LINE_NO = (SELECT ORDER_LINE_NO 
                       FROM [dbo].[ORDER_DETAIL] 
                       WHERE RATE_STRUCTURE = 'LIST' 
                         AND ORDER_NO = @ip_order_id 
                         AND SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = @ip_master_customer_id 
                       LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1 
                       ORDER BY ORDER_LINE_NO DESC)
```

Comment: What is "MAX - 1 record"?  Sample data and desired results is VERY helpful.

Comment: Is `LIMIT` a thing in SQL Server?  Maybe you want `TOP`.

Comment: TOP is not a option here for this example because the offset ignores first result and TOP does not have this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the exact syntax you should use for your inner select:

```
SELECT ORDER_LINE_NO 
FROM [dbo].[ORDER_DETAIL] 
WHERE RATE_STRUCTURE = 'LIST' 
AND ORDER_NO = @ip_order_id 
AND SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = @ip_master_customer_id 
ORDER BY ORDER_LINE_NO DESC
OFFSET 1 ROW
FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY
```

And then your update statement will be like this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[ORDER_DETAIL] SET LINE_STATUS_CODE ='C' 
WHERE RATE_STRUCTURE = 'LIST' 
AND RATE_CODE= 'PRIMARY' 
AND SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = @ip_master_customer_id
AND [ORDER_NO] = @ip_order_id  
AND ORDER_LINE_NO = (SELECT ORDER_LINE_NO 
                     FROM [dbo].[ORDER_DETAIL] 
                     WHERE RATE_STRUCTURE = 'LIST' 
                     AND ORDER_NO = @ip_order_id  
                     AND SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = @ip_master_customer_id
                     ORDER BY ORDER_LINE_NO DESC
                     OFFSET 1 ROW
                     FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY);
```

[Here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fa94098b1d30688904e52383773843fc)

P.S. SQL Server does not have `LIMIT`, you can use `TOP` or `OFFSET` with `FETCH NEXT`. If you want to use TOP you can not use the offset to start from second result or third result.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want something akin to the second-to-last record from `Order_Detail` based on the matching and filtering criteria you have set up:

```
UPDATE od
    SET LINE_STATUS_CODE ='C'
    FROM (SELECT od.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ORDER_LINE_NO DESC) as seqnum
          FROM [dbo].[ORDER_DETAIL] od
          WHERE RATE_STRUCTURE = 'LIST' AND RATE_CODE= 'PRIMARY' AND
                SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = @ip_master_customer_id  AND 
                [ORDER_NO] = @ip_order_id 
        ) od
    WHERE seqnum = 2;
```